# Restart countdown at specific time

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have multiple countdown timer and a real time digital clock that is running and working. I am using jQuery.countdown script library http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html for my countdown. When my countdown is finish or reaches 00:00:00, I stop the countdown and display '00:00:00'. This works without issue. But what I want is after a specific time, let's say if the digiclock is 08:00:00 I want to restart the countdown. The jQuery.Countdown library has a function pause/start maybe this is what I need but I don't know how to implement it.

```
<div id="realtime-digiclock">08:00:00</div>

<?php
$dateToday = date("Y-m-d");
?>

<span class="countdown" value="<?php echo $dateToday; ?> 00:10:00"></span>
<span class="countdown" value="<?php echo $dateToday; ?> 00:20:00"></span>
<span class="countdown" value="<?php echo $dateToday; ?> 00:30:00"></span>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hilios/jQuery.countdown@master/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<script>
            
$(function(){        
      $('.countdown').each(function(){
         $(this).countdown($(this).attr('value'), function(event) {
         $(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
      }).on('finish.countdown', function(e) {
          $(this).text("00:00:00");
        });
    });
 });   
</script>
    <!-- Digiclock - https://jquerycards.com/forms/date-time/jclocksgmt-js/--> 
<script>
 $(function(){ 
  $('#realtime-digiclock').jClocksGMT({ title:'', offset:'-4', timeformat:'hh:mm:ss a', skin: 2, analog: false });
    });                 
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. The digiclock is a real time clock. It's not always 8am.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [jQuery.Countdown docs](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html), but it doesn't mention a "reset" function. *However*, if you check the [source code in countdown.js](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/blob/master/src/countdown.js) you can see that there are several methods than you can use, beside those mentioned in the docs - the one that you need is `.setFinalDate(value)` -> because you can rewrite when the countdown stops.

For example, let's say you have a countdown timer (`#countdown1`) you want to "reset" when it reaches the end. Let's say `timeNow = 2020-09-20 17:00:00` and `deadline1 = 2020-09-20 17:00:10`. The countdown timer will run for *10 seconds* then will set the `finish.countdown` event and stop. At this moment, you want to "reset" it for the next time: `deadline2 = 2020-09-20 17:00:20`, so the timer will run for *another 10 seconds*. The code you need for this example is this:

Here is the [jsfiddle working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ap8wu09h/1/):

```
<!-- resources -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hilios/jQuery.countdown@master/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<!-- demo html - one countdown -->
<span id="countdown1" value=""></span>

<script>
/* demo vars...*/
var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
var deadline1 = timeNow + 10 * 1000; // after 10 seconds
var deadline2 = timeNow + 20 * 1000; // after 20 seconds (10 seconds after first deadline)
/* setup the countdown */
$("#countdown1").countdown(deadline1, function (event) {
      $(this).text(event.strftime("%H:%M:%S"));
    })
.on("finish.countdown", function(e){
  var $target = $(this);
  if (e.timeStamp < deadline2) {
    alert("First deadline reached! -> continue to next one...");
    /** RESET THE COUNTDOWN -> .setFinalDate() method **/
    $target.countdown("setFinalDate", deadline2);
    /** RESTART THE COUNTDOWN **/
    $target.countdown("start")
  } else {
    alert("Second deadline reached! -> END");
  }
});
</script>
```

I hope this demo will help you.